# Fat-Free-Framework: How to add/modify/delete records of related table using DB\SQL\Mapper

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

Hi everyone I'm currently working on a form that includes rows from a related table and processing the form has presented a challenge: In F3, what is the best method to handle a form that may result in rows in a related table being added, modified or deleted?

**DB Schema**

```html
practitioner
------------------------------
id         | int(10)
first_name | varchar(255)
last_name  | varchar(255)
abn        | char(11)
mobile     | varchar(20)
email      | varchar(255)

practice_site
------------------------------
id         | int(10)
name       | varchar(255)

provider_number
------------------------------
id               | int(10)
practice_site_id | int(10)
practitioner_id  | int(10)
provider_number  | varchar(20)
```

**The Form**

- Provider numbers are added dynamically, form names are amended with `_n`, e.g. `provider_number_3`
- The delete button removes the row altogether, meaning there may be `provider_number_1` and `provider_number_3` but no `provider_number_2`

[image]

**Form Output**

The provider numbers are transformed into something a bit more manageable than `*_n`.

Other fields, `id`, `first_name`, etc are easily updated thanks to `copyfrom()`.

```php
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [first_name] => Jon
    [last_name] => Doctor
    [abn] => 12345678902
    [mobile] => 0491729472
    [email] => john.doctor@email.com
    [provider_numbers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [provider_number] => ASBDF24
                    [practice_site_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [provider_number] => 1249FBK
                    [practice_site_id] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

**The Problem**

A few conditions about provider numbers can occur when the form is submitted:

- A new provider number is added
- A provider number is changed
- A practice site is changed
- A provider number is removed

How would be the best way to go about this? (Preferably using Fat-Free-Framework's `DB\SQL\Mapper` class).

Possible solution:

- Do a `$db->exec()` to get an array of existing `provider_number` table where `provider_id = POST.id`
- Perform an `array_diff()` to find any records in database that aren't in form then do a `DELETE` statement on those records. Truncate the original array.
- Traverse through array looking whether the `provider_number`s match. If they do, but `practice_site_id` is different, update. If `practice_site_id` is the same, do nothing.
- How to accurately determine if a `provider_number` has changed for a particular `practice_site_id`?

Another possibility:

- Change the form to include `provider_number.id`, when a new row is added, grab the newest available ID from the database

Comment: Your last suggestion looks like the simplest solution (include `provider_number.id`). This way, you just need to `$providerNumber->load(['id=?',$id])` and the mapper will automatically insert or update depending on wether or not the id matches an existing record. You also need to track deleted records. That could be accomplished with an extra hidden boolean `erase` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion from @xfra35 in my question, I went with the second possibility - Adding `provider_number.id` to the form itself and going from there. If you have any further suggestions or advice, please feel free to share!

The form was modified so that values were inserted into `provider_numbers[provider_number][] and provider_numbers[practice_site_id][]` instead of `practice_site_1, practice_site_2, etc`. This has made the code for dynamically inserting the rows *much easier* as `*_n` no longer needs to be tracked.

`<div class="delete-array">` was placed inside the form and whenever the delete button was clicked, the following was inserted: `<input type="hidden" name="provider_numbers[delete][]" value="' + id + '" />`.

The new button fetches the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value from the database and has some basic logic if more than one provider number is being added at a time. (*Caveat: Will break if multiple users manipulating this function at the same time*)

```
var new_id;
$('.btn-add-provider-number').click(function() {

    if (typeof(new_id) === "undefined") {
        $.getJSON({url:'{{ @BASE }}/provider_numbers/new_id.json', async:false}).done(function(data) {
            new_id = data;
        });
    } else {
        new_id++;
    }

    var newRow = ' .... ';
    $('.provider-numbers').append(newRow);
}
```

A form submit now looks something like:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [first_name] => Amy
    [last_name] => Doctor
    [abn] => 66627819264
    [mobile] => 0472888798
    [email] => amy.doctor@email.com
    [provider_numbers] => Array
        (
            [delete] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                )

            [provider_number] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 64872HJF
                    [1] => 182947KD
                )

            [practice_site_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

Then is handled with the following code:

```
$updated = [];
$provider_numbers = [];
$provider_numbers_delete = [];

foreach ($f3->get('POST') as $key => $val) {
    if ($key == 'provider_numbers') {
        foreach ($val as $pn_key => $pn_val) {
            if ($pn_key !== 'delete') {
                foreach ($pn_val as $pnk_key => $pnk_val) {
                    $provider_numbers[$pnk_key][$pn_key] = $pnk_val;
                }
            } else {
                $provider_numbers_delete = $pn_val;
            }
        }
    } else if (is_scalar($val) && $practitioner->exists($key)) {
        $practitioner->set($key, $val);
        $updated[] = $key;
    }
}

if (!empty($provider_numbers)) {
    foreach($provider_numbers as $pn) {
        $provider_number->load(['id = ?', $pn['id']]);
        if ($provider_number->dry()) {
            $provider_number->set('practitioner_id', $f3->get('POST.id'));
        }
        $provider_number->copyfrom($pn);
        $provider_number->save();   
        $updated['provider_numbers'][] = $pn;
    }
}

if (!empty($provider_numbers_delete)) {
    foreach ($provider_numbers_delete as $pnd) {
        $provider_number->load(['id = ?', $pnd]);
        if (!$provider_number->dry()) {
            $provider_number->delete(); 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: NB: you don't need to guess the next auto_increment id. A `NULL` value is enough.

Comment: Oh awesome! I will modify ASAP